# Symfony forms insert only one field in database

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I got 3 entities: Languages, Countries and SetupWizard which contains a ManyToOne relation with the former entities through languageID and countryID properties.
I also have a SetupWizardType so i can build the form in the following way:

```
$builder
    ->add('language', EntityType::class, [
        'translation_domain' => 'labels',
        'label' => 'label.languages',
        'placeholder' => false,
        'class' => Languages::class,
    ])
    ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
        'translation_domain' => 'labels',
        'label' => 'label.countries',
        'placeholder' => false,
        'class' => Countries::class
    ]);
```

As you can see, the final form will have 2 select field with their options and when the user selects an option from the Languages selectbox, a jquery event will trigger which submits the form and pass the job to my controller:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$setupWizard = $entityManager->getRepository(SetupWizard::class)->findSetup(1)
    ?? new SetupWizard();

$form = $this->createForm(SetupWizardType::class, $setupWizard);
$form->handleRequest($request);
$userLanguage = $form->get('language');

if ( $form->isSubmitted() ) {

    $submittedData = $form->getData();

    if( !empty($userLanguage->getData()) && empty($_POST['save']) ){

        $setupWizard->setLanguage($userLanguage->getData());
        $entityManager->persist($setupWizard);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('wizard_index');

    } elseif( $form->isValid() && !empty($_POST['save']) ) {

        $entityManager->persist($submittedData);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_homepage');
    }
}
```

What is this doing? Well, there are two cases, in the first a language option has been chosen so i save it in db and on the next page load a subscriber checks it and changes the locale so i can display the further fields/data of this form with the desired language.On the second case, it checks if the entire form has been completed and is valid so i can insert all of the values in the db.

Why i've done it like this? I didnt knew a better way to be honest... ajax is out of disscusion because i need the data to be rendered in the chosen language, and that's possible only by server side coding...i think.If you know a better way of doing this,please let me know.
What's the problem with my code? In the first case i wanted to insert only the language, instead all of the fields are added...This could be because i used EntityType fields and when i `$entityManager->persist($setupWizard);` it saves the entire object.Is there a way to persist only the language value?

P.S. let me know if you think a piece of my code could be refactored into a better one, that would help me learn more since i'm a newbie with symfony/doctrine.

Comment: AJAX means using js to call the server (and delegate most of the computating to it), so I don't get your point about AJAX

Comment: @greg0ire , i could use ajax to send the language id to a route where i insert it in db.The benefit of this is that i get rid of page reload, yet the changes won't show on the rest of the form data since i need that page reload for php to do his job...